# Inverse of Sine and Csc - without using a calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm taking precalc and have the following problems:

Find the exact value of each expression:

a) $\sin^{-1}(\sin \frac{4\pi}{3})$

b) $\csc (\cos^{-1} \frac{12}{13})$

I get the general gist of Inverse functions - they provide an angle when supplied with two sides - but beyond plugging them into a calculator I don't know how to do these by hand. I know for a), $\sin \frac{4\pi}{3} = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, but proceeding from there baffles me. Could someone walk me through this? Do I need the Pythagorean theorem?

Comment: Hint. The relation between $\sin$ and its inverse is like the relation between squaring and taking square roots.

Comment: What is cps in part b)?

Comment: @Element118 : "o" and "p" are adjacent on standard QWERTY keyboards, so I am presuming that was supposed to be $\cos$. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Your method of punctuating comments is very memorable for Android users because you have to click a button to render MathJax in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\cos \theta = \frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}} = \frac{12}{13}.
$$
So draw the triangle where the adjacent side has length $12$ and the hypotenuse has length $13$, and use the Pythagorean theorem to find the opposite side:
$$
\text{opposite} = \sqrt{13^2 - 12^2} = \sqrt{169-144} = \sqrt{25} = 5.
$$
Then we have
$$
\csc\theta = \frac{\text{hypotenuse}}{\text{opposite}} = \frac{13} 5.
$$
I.e.
$$
\csc\left( \cos^{-1} \frac{12}{13} \right) = \frac{13} 5.
$$
These things can be done quickly by drawing the triangles.